# Finding the likelihood of a string across multiple columns?

Tags: google-sheets, multiple-columns, probability, percentage, similarity

I'm working with film production rental data and am interested in generating an ideal rental package based on the rental histories of 4 similar customers.

I have separated their rentals into 4 tables and would like to sort a new list of "Items" based on their likelihood of being rented again...which I'm assuming would be based on how often an "Item" intersects all 4 rental histories? Even finding this percentage alone would greatly help.

Having no prior statistics experience, I'm at a loss as far as best practices are concerned and any insight at all would be greatly appreciated. The example below has 4 rental histories with # of times rented. I've generated a unique list of items in column M.

[Example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SIe_t9X5oBP_e_m--ccKJW7D5Pad60F88-UO3PO3ZSU/edit#gid=0)

Answer (score 0):

You can try `QUERY`:

```
=QUERY({A3:B;D3:E;G3:H;J3:K},
 "SELECT Col1, SUM(Col2), COUNT(Col1), COUNT(Col1)/4*100 
  GROUP BY Col1 
  ORDER BY COUNT(Col1) DESC 
  LABEL Col1 'Item', 
        SUM(Col2) 'Sum Of Rentals', 
        COUNT(Col1) 'Count in Lists', 
        COUNT(Col1)/4*100 'Percentage in Lists'")
```

[image]